# Why startup-script runs multiple times in Google compute engine vm?

Tags: virtual-machine, script, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I don't understand why my startup-script runs multiple times
at least, I think so because after I started the vm this morning at 6:00am
now I just logged into google cloud console, checked the logs and
saw that the startup script run multiple times
I thought it was meant to run just once :/

```
Nov 21 06:57:11 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 06:57:11 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 06:57:11 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:12:17 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:12:17 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:12:17 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:27:10 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:27:10 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:27:10 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
Nov 21 07:42:13 ubuntu startup-script: INFO startup-script: stuff...
...
```

and more

any idea why the vm has that behaviour?

note that I added the `startup-script` in the instance Custom metadata:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -iu user2 Desktop/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add checker on your script if you want one time running . for example :

```
if [[ -f /etc/startup_was_launched ]]; then exit 0; fi
…
touch /etc/startup_was_launched
```

or

```
if [ ! -f /etc/startup_was_launched ];then
...
sudo touch /etc/startup_was_launched
fi
```